# Find all $z\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $i\sin\left(z\right)+\cosh\left(iz\right)=\left(1+i\sqrt{3}\right)^i$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Firstly, I tried using the identity $\cos\left(ix\right)=\cosh\left(x\right)$ to arrive at this expression: $$i\sin\left(z\right)+\cos\left(z\right)=\left(1+i\sqrt{3}\right)^i$$
Then, using Euler's formula, I got: $$e^{iz}=\left(1+i\sqrt{3}\right)^i$$

That's where I'm at. I thought about using logarithms but I'm not comfortable using them in the complex realm. Thanks.

Comment: (1) Is $\;j=i=\sqrt{-1}\;$ ? (2) Is it exponent $\;i\;$ in the right hand or multiplication by $\;i\;$ out of the parentheses on the right?

Comment: Yes! Sorry, $j = i$. I'll edit the question for clarity. The $i$ on the right side is the exponent of the whole parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using $\;z=x+iy\;$ (eventually):

$$i\sin z+\cos z=i\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}+\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}2=e^{iz}=e^{i(x+iy)}=e^{-y}(\cos x+i\sin x)$$

On the other hand ( choosing say the standard value of the argument in $\;(-\pi,\pi)\;$ )

$$1+\sqrt3\,i=2e^{\pi i/3}\implies\left(1+\sqrt3\,i\right)^i=2^i e^{-\pi/3}$$

Finally,

$$2^i=e^{i\left(\ln 2\right)}=\cos\ln 2+i\sin\ln 2$$

Now put the above together...

Answer (score 1):

Since $1+j\sqrt{3}=e^{\ln2+\pi j/3+2n\pi j}$ with $n\in\Bbb Z$, $(1+j\sqrt{3})^j$ is multivalued as $e^{j[\ln 2+\pi j/3+2n\pi j]}$, so $z=\ln 2+\pi j/3+2n\pi j$.

Comment: Thanks for answering. As I understand, when working with complex numbers, $e^{z_1} = e^{z_2}$ does not always imply $z_1 = z_2$. Is not that the case here? And if so, why is that?

Comment: @Morganuz My answer has used the fact that $e^{z_1}=e^{z_2}$ iff some integer $n$ satisfies $z_1=z_2+2n\pi j$.